# Objective function and constraints are matrix form in an optimization problem, can Lagrange multipliers method be applied to solve?

Tags: matrix-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, quadratic-programming, qcqp

I would like to solve the following optimization problem:

given $\mathbf{K} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\mathbf{P_{0}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 3}$, $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 3}$, $\mathbf{N} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$, $\mathbf{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$ and $m,k < n$. We want to get $\mathbf{P}$ by solving the following optimization problem:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
minimize \  \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{KP-P_{0}}\|_{F}^{2} 
\end{array}
$$

$$
subject \ to: \
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\quad \mathbf{MP=A} \\
\mathbf{(N P \odot N P)} \mathbf{1}_{3}=\mathbf{L}
\end{array}\right.
$$

where $\mathbf{P} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 3}$, $\mathbf{1}_{3}\in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 1}$ is a vector with all the elements equal to 1, $\odot$ is Hadamard product (elements-wise product).

You can understand the above problem with a specific meaning. The objective function $\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{KP-P_{0}}\|_{F}^{2}$ (square of F-norm) or $\frac{1}{2}\langle\mathbf{KP-P_{0}}, \mathbf{KP-P_{0}}\rangle_{\mathrm{F}}$ (Frobenius inner product) is the sum of Euclidean distance of a points list, $\mathbf{P_{0}}$ is their original 3D coordinates and $\mathbf{KP}$ is the changed coordinates.
Condition 1 $\mathbf{MP=A}$ can be seen as positional constraints, that is the coordinates of several points can be changed. And condition 2 $\mathbf{(N P \odot N P) 1}=\mathbf{L}$ is the length constraints, that is distances between some points are invariants.

Objective function and constraints are matrix form, I am not sure whether can it be seen as a **QP** or **QCQP** problem but with equality constraints. Will there be a closed-form solution? How to solve it? Or any known solver can be used to solve this problem?

---

One of my ideas is using Lagrange multipliers method, the objective function $\frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf{KP-P_{0}}\|_{F}^{2} $ is a scalar, but the constraints are matrix, we can not simply add them up.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Form the Lagrangian as $L(P, Y, Z) := \frac{1}{2}\| KP - P_0\|_F^2 + {\rm Tr}( Y^T (MP-A) ) + {\rm Tr}( Z^T ((NP \odot NP )1_3 - L ) )$, where $Y$ and $Z$ are Lagrange multipliers (the elements can also be negative as it is an equality constraint). Then, take the gradient of the Lagrangian with respect to $P$ and see how it looks after setting it to zero (if you are lucky then you may find a closed-form solution). I have not taken the gradient. You may try to use CVX solver.

Comment: Also, you need to consider the constraints for computing the Lagrange multipliers $Y$ and $Z$. In other words, if you take the gradient with respect to the respective Lagrange multipliers and set it to zero, you will get the constraints which need to be satisfied

Comment: Get you, thanks @user550103 . Here  **_I have not taken the gradient. You may try to use CVX solver._**, do you mean that CVX solver can be used this problem directly without taken the gradient manually? That would be better. But it's difficult to rewrite it to a standard format that can be input to the CVX solver. Any advise?

Comment: Yes, you do not need to take the gradient of the Lagrangian to feed it into the solver such as CVX.

Comment: @user550103 I have tried to used CVX solver to solve this problem, however, a `DCPError`  throwed caused by the hadamard constraint $\mathbf{(N P \odot N P)} \mathbf{1}_{3}=\mathbf{L}$, which is non-convex, and CVX solver can not handle it. Do you have any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Can relaxing that constraint help? Instead of equality, would you prefer $\left( NP \odot NP \right)1_3 - L \leq 0$?

Comment: $\mathbf{(N P \odot N P)} \mathbf{1}_{3}$ is actually a length list and $\mathbf{L}$ is that it what to achieve, somethint like that $x^2+y^2+z^2=l$. So in this case, relaxing make no sense.

Comment: It is more like a sphere, isn't it?  If you want to keep the solution only on the boundary of the sphere, then I am afraid your problem is nonconvex. If you allow solutions to be within the sphere as well (like in typical $\ell_2$ norm ball), your problem can be convex. If you are lucky, then the solution may not be far from the boundary... Sorry, I cannot be of more help. Perhaps, some experts can help you better than I.

Comment: @user550103 Thanks anyway, you help me a lot! I am trying to test some non-convex solver.